# Call a method from arraylist element

Tags: java, reflection, methods, arraylist

Im new to Java and I completely stuck on it.
I have to implement "summator" class, to summ all Numbers in it.
For example this class holds a number

```
public class NumericNode <N extends Number>{    
    private N nodeValue = null;
    public NumericNode(N initValue){
        this.nodeValue = initValue;
    }
    public N getNodeValue() {
        return nodeValue;
    }
}
```

second class need to do some summ

```
public class NumericSummatorNode<NumericNode, T> {    
    private T nodeValue;
    private NumericNode[] inlets;
public NumericSummatorNode(NumericNode...inlets) {
        this.summ(inlets);
    }//constructor
public void summ(NumericNode... summValues) {
        ArrayList<NumericNode> numericList = new ArrayList<>();       
        int count = summValues.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
           numericList.add(summValues[i]);
        }
       for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
           Method method = numericList.get(j).getClass().getMethod("getNodeValue", null);
           method.invoke(numericList.get(j), null);
        }    
     }
```

And here is the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        NumericNode n1 = new NumericNode(5);
        NumericNode n2 = new NumericNode(4.3f);
        NumericNode n3 = new NumericNode(24.75d);
        NumericNode n5 = new NumericNode((byte)37);
        NumericNode n6 = new NumericNode((long)4674);
        NumericSummatorNode s1 = new NumericSummatorNode(5, 4.6f, (double)4567);
        NumericSummatorNode s2 = new NumericSummatorNode(n1, n2);
        NumericSummatorNode s3 = new NumericSummatorNode();        
        s2.summ(n1, n2);        
    }//main
```

So I have an issue to call getNodeValue() method from an NumericNode object in my array list.
How do I make this work?

Comment: what is the exception??

Comment: NuSuchMethodException and some exceptions else. But it still not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at what the exception says, it tells you what is wrong. The exception probably says:

> `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.getNodeValue()`

So the list apparently contains Integers, even though it appears that `ArrayList<NumericNode>` should contain only `NumericNode`. How can this happen? If I run it in eclipse, it also shows this warning:

> The type parameter NumericNode is hiding the type NumericNode

This is caused because the class is declared as

```
public class NumericSummatorNode<NumericNode, T>
```

`NumericNode` is a type argument that unfortunately shares the same name as the `NumericNode` class. This means it hides the real `NumericNode` class and you can't use it anymore. This is also the reason why  `new NumericSummatorNode(5, 4.6f, (double) 4567)` even compiles. You can't just pass any `Number` to a constructor that actually takes `NumericNode`.

So restructure it to `NumericSummatorNode<T>` or maybe `NumericSummatorNode<N extends NumericNode, T>` or whatever your intention was there, so it won't hide any classes. It won't compile any more, so you will also need to adapt the types of your constructor and sum method. Also it's nice to use generics, but are they kind of useless if you are using raw types anyway.

Comment: Thank your for this explicit explanation. Exactly you was right. I remake my code in "summator" class, it is now work with ArrayList and invoking methods from list. The problem redused to simple reflection example)))